# Count user login attempts using IBAction button

Tags: swift, ibaction

I want to count how many times login button is clicked. If username and passwords field are empty and login button is clicked I want the count to be incremented by 1.

As I can not take "count" as inout parameter in this IBAction function, how can I accomplish this task?

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    var count : Int = 0
    if (Username.text!.isEmpty || Password.text!.isEmpty ) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "All fields are required to fill in", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(OkAction)
        self.present(myAlert,animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
```

Comment: Make the count variable as an instance variable

Comment: You can increment the sender tag by 1
`@IBAction func loginButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if (Username.text!.isEmpty || Password.text!.isEmpty ) {
   sender.tag = sender.tag + 1
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YOU CAN USE STATIC VARIABLES:**

```
class MyLogs {
    static var numberOfLoginAttempts = 0

    init() {}

    func loginAttempt() {
        numberOfLoginAttempts += 1
    }

}
```

**USAGE:**

`let logs = MyLogs()`

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    logs.loginAttempt()
    print("Login Attempt Number : \(MyLogs.numberOfLoginAttempts)")
    var count : Int = 0
    if (Username.text!.isEmpty || Password.text!.isEmpty ) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "All fields are required to fill in", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(OkAction)
        self.present(myAlert,animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
}
```

**If You Want To Close The Application And Still Have The Number Of Logins:**

Take a look at [CoreData](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

Comment: print("Login Attempt Number : \(logs.numberOfLoginAttempts)") 
it gives me error that "Static member numberOfLoginAttempts can not be used of instance of type MyLogs"
I have removed static and it is working. Thank you

Comment: Glad i could help. About the static, I updated it. Check it out. Sorry about that